# Breeze to$q: $log is not defined

Tags: angularjs, breeze, promise, q

If you tack a "fail()" on one of breeze's Q that doesn't re-throw the error, it tries to log a message to tell you that.

It says (line 58 of breeze.to$q.js: https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze/blob/master/Breeze.Client/Scripts/Labs/breeze.to%24q.js) :

```
$log.error("Programming error: no data. " +
                    "Perhaps success callback didn't return a value or " +
                        "fail callback didn't re-throw error");
```

...but $log is not defined, so I get a javascript error.

Am I doing something wrong (other than not re-throwing the error), or is that a bug?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if you are aware that to$q will be depreciated.
check out the new breeze.angular.q approach:
http://www.breezejs.com/breeze-labs/breezeangularqjs